# Finding no solutions and many infinitely many solutions for $k$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\left(
    \begin{array}{crr|c}
    1 & k & -1 &   2\\
    2 & -1 & k &   5 \\ 
    1 & 10 & -6 &  1 \\
     \end{array}
\right)  \xrightarrow[\text{$R_3=R_3-R_1$}]{\text{$R_2=R_2-2R_1$}}$$ $$\left(
    \begin{array}{ccc|r}
    1 & k & -1 &  2\\
    0 & -1-2k & k+2 &  1 \\ 
    0 & 10-k & -5 & -1 \\
     \end{array}
\right) \xrightarrow[\text{$R_3=R_3-(\frac{10-k}{2k+1})R_2$}]{} (2k+1\neq0)$$
$$\left(
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
    1 & k & -1 & 2\\
    0 & -1-2k & k+2 & 5 \\ 
    0 & 0 & \frac{-k^2-2k+15}{2k+1} & \frac{-3k+9}{2k+1} \\
     \end{array}
\right) $$
Which has a unique solution $\iff \frac{-3k+9}{2k+1} \neq 0 \iff -3k+9\neq 0 \iff k\neq3$

Now how can I show that it got no solutions and infinitely many solutions. Not sure how to do it when I got so difficult equation for $k$. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The system as a unique solution if $\frac {-k^2-2k+15}{2k+1} \ne 0$. If it is equal to zero, it has no solutions if $\frac{-3k+9}{2k+1} \ne 0$ and infinitely many solutions otherwise.

Comment: @player3236 what do you mean infinitely many solutions otherwise?

Comment: "Otherwise", in this context, means $\frac {-3k+9}{2k+1} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have to divide by $2k+1$! Once you have row reduced to an upper triangular form, you can just consider the equations they represent:

There are no solutions if you end up with a row like

$$(0\ 0\ \ldots\ 0\ |\ x)$$

for some nonzero $x$ (the corresponding equation is a contradiction!), and

$$(0\ 0\ \ldots\ 0\ |\ 0)$$

indicates freedom to choose the variables as you like, hence choice (with infinitely many choices).

One way to think about it is about singularness of the 3×3 matrix on the left:

If it is invertible (full rank), there is exactly one solution.

If it is non-invertible (i.e., does not have full rank), then it will have either infinitely many solutions, or none, depending on whether the target on the right gets hit or not.

As it so happens, your matrix is non-invertible for $k = 3$ or $-5$ (by determinant of the original or reduced matrix), so, that given, you only really need check these values.